# How to hold a node api execution till a db query does not return null

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api

Seems rather like an unwanted requirement for a piece of code but in my case this is exactly what I need. I have an api (API-1) that interacts with a third party service. This third party service instead of directly giving me a response that I can forward back to frontend is giving me response on API-2 (With a webhook listener endpoint). I'm saving this API-2 response that I get by listening to the webhook in my database. Now I somehow need this response which is now sitting idol in my database in my API-1 so that I can forward it back to the frontend. If I query the database right away during the flow of the API-1 (Just after consume the third party service API), I'll get null as API-2 is getting the response asynchronously with a webhook (Mostly a gap of 1-2 seconds). So I somehow need to figure out an easy way to await/hold the API-1 flow till the database does not return null/returns back the response I saved from API-2 in the database. I'm not sure if the gap will always be 1-2 seconds hence I can't be using setTimeout for this.

```
//API-1
const sendPaymentRequest = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const payment_reponse = await axios.post(url, body, config);
    const { data } = payment_reponse;
    console.log("Payment request => ", data);

    //Check result i.e response from http listener
    const webhookResponse = await MpesaModel.findOne({
      conversationId: data.ConversationID
    });

    console.log('Webhook response => ', webhookResponse); //This is null

    res.status(200).json({ message: "Send money request", data });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error while making a payment request", error);
    res
      .status(400)
      .json({ message: "Error while send payment request", error: error.data });
  }
};


//API-2 - This is the webhook which receives the response
const saveWebhookB2C = async (req, res) => {
  const { Result } = req.body;
  //console.log('Mpesa webhook data received => ', Result);

  let saveResponse = new MpesaModel({
    ...Result,
  });
  const result = await saveResponse.save();
  console.log('B2c mpesa to kenya saved in db => ', result);
  res.status(200).send();
};
```

Comment: Write your own promise and don't resolve it until you'll `saveResponse.save()` - then await that custom response inside `sendPaymentRequest()` - that way, you control the timing of the resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wait until the response is different than null:

```
let webhookResponse = null;
while (response === null) {
  await sleep(1000);
  webhookResponse = await MpesaModel.findOne({
    conversationId: data.ConversationID,
  });
  
}
```

The sleep function should be fairly simple (and we use it only to wait one second until the next query):

```
const sleep = (timeInMilliseconds) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), timeInMilliseconds);
  });
};
```

Note: the while loop will run forever if the answer is always null, so probably you want to add another condition to the while in case the result is always null (maybe a maximum number of tries?).

Comment: This worked perfectly well glad I got to learn a new ninja technique

Answer (score 0):

```
async function getNotNullResponse({conversationId}){
    const webhookResponse = await MpesaModel.findOne({conversationId});
    return webhookResponse || getNotNullResponse({conversationId});
}

//API-1
const sendPaymentRequest = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const payment_reponse = await axios.post(url, body, config);
    const { data } = payment_reponse;
    console.log("Payment request => ", data);

    //Check result i.e response from http listener
    const webhookResponse = await getNotNullResponse({
      conversationId: data.ConversationID
    });

    console.log('Webhook response => ', webhookResponse); //This is not null

    res.status(200).json({ message: "Send money request", data });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error while making a payment request", error);
    res
      .status(400)
      .json({ message: "Error while send payment request", error: error.data });
  }
};


//API-2 - This is the webhook which receives the response
const saveWebhookB2C = async (req, res) => {
  const { Result } = req.body;
  //console.log('Mpesa webhook data received => ', Result);

  let saveResponse = new MpesaModel({
    ...Result,
  });
  const result = await saveResponse.save();
  console.log('B2c mpesa to kenya saved in db => ', result);
  res.status(200).send();
};
```